# JavaScript Function - Change content in a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loading

I have a problem. I have this function:

```
    function isDone()
{ 
    if(isDone){
    $("#loadingStatus").html("NOT DONE...");
    }else{
    $("#loadingStatus").html("#isDone");    
    }
}
```

The above code does NOT work. The code above is checking if the content in an iFrame is done loading.

What i want is to have a div that says if it is NOT loaded "NOT DONE..." but if it is loaded then output another DIV into the #loadingStatus div.

UPDATE:

This is my 100 % code.

```
<?php
$key = $_GET['key'];
$s=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM advertisements WHERE `key`='$key'")
or die(mysql_error());
$r=mysql_fetch_assoc($s);

?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../divided/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../dream/js/iframeLoad.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function isDone()
{ 
    if(isDone){
    $("#loadingStatus").html("Waiting for your advertisements to load...");
    }else{
    $("#loadingStatus").html($("#isDone").html());  
    }


}
</script>
</head>

<div style="height:10%">
    <table style="border:black;">
        <tr>
            <td><img src="../dream/images/logo.png"></td>
            <td><div id="loadingStatus"></div></td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div id="isDone" style="display:none">

    </div>



</div>



<iframe onload="isDone()" src="<?php echo $r['url']; ?>" width="100%" height="90%" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0">
<p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

Comment: And what *exactly* is not working?

Comment: It does not show the "NOT DONE..." when the iframe is NOT loaded.

Comment: @Oliver: Well, your code only _does stuff_ "onload", so... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for:

```
$("#loadingStatus").html($("#isDone").html());
```

**EDIT:** In your code, `isDone` is a function, not a variable. From what I understand, you have to do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#loadingStatus").text("Waiting for your advertisements to load...");
});

function isDone()
{ 
    $("#loadingStatus").html($("#isDone").html());  
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But what about the rest of the issue. When it is NOT done loading, it should show NOT DONE. When it is done, I will use:
$("#loadingStatus").html($("#isDone").html());

How does the code look like then?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by `loading`. If you're sending an AJAX request, you can do that in its `success` callback. It's difficult to answer properly without seeing more of your code.

Comment: Well. I have an iFrame on my page. The function isDone() is checking if the iframe SRC is done loading.

Comment: @Oliver - Generally, you want to add the `Not Done` text when you first start loading, so that'll probably be in the first few lines of the `click` event handler that begins the trigger to fetch content.... then this entire `isDone()` function or its functionality should go into the `success` handler.,, So handling `Not Done` should not be within `isDone()`.

Answer (score 1):

Because the function isn't called until the iFrame is loaded, the not loaded message will not appear.

You need to have some default text in the `isDone` div.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/sMGTU/

```
<?php
    $key = $_GET['key'];
    $s=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM advertisements WHERE `key`='$key'")
    or die(mysql_error());
    $r=mysql_fetch_assoc($s);
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../divided/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../dream/js/iframeLoad.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var iFrameLoaded=false;

function checkDone(iFrameLoaded)
{
    iFrameLoaded
       ? $("#loadingStatus").html("Finished Loading")
       : $("#loadingStatus").html("Waiting for your advertisements to load...");
}

</script>
</head>

<div style="height:10%">
    <table style="border:black;">
        <tr>
            <td><img src="../dream/images/logo.png"></td>
            <td><div id="loadingStatus"></div></td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="isDone" style="display:none"></div>
</div>

<iframe onload="checkDone(true);"
        src="<?php echo $r['url']; ?>"
        width="100%" height="90%"
        scrolling="auto"
        frameborder="0">
   <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new div:

```
$("#loadingStatus").append($("<div/>").text("Done."));
```

If you want to move a div from somewhere else:

```
$("#loadingStatus").append($("#isDone"));
```

If you want to copy a div from somewhere else:

```
$("#loadingStatus").append($("#isDone").clone());
```

If you want to move the contents of an element:

```
$("#loadingStatus").append($("#isDone").children());
```

If you want to copy the contents of an element:

```
$("#loadingStatus").append($("#isDone").children().clone());
```

#### Update:

Seeing the rest of the code reveals some more problems with it. As you don't have any variable that determines if the content has loaded or not, and only call the function once the content is loaded, just put the code for changing the content in the function. Put the initial message directly in the element.

```
function isDone() { 
  $("#loadingStatus").append($("#isDone").children().clone());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is isDone variable set in the code? Do you have any load event handler for iframe?

Try this

```
$(function(){

 $("#loadingStatus").html("Waiting for your advertisements to load...");

var isDone = false;
function checkIsDone()
{ 
    if(isDone){
       $("#loadingStatus").html("NOT DONE...");
    }else{
       $("#loadingStatus").html($("#isDone").html());    
    }
}

$("iframeSelector").load(function(){

  isDone = true;

});

checkIsDone();

});
```

Comment: And now the variable is completely redundant.

Comment: @Shankar: The variable is _still_ completely redundant; you didn't "correct" anything to address that. Your code will work, but it can be terser (see my answer).

Comment: @Tom - The OP wants to check whether the iframe is loaded or no and based on it set the appropriate status message. He doesnt want to set the message after iframe is loaded. In your code you are setting it after the iframe is loaded.

Comment: @Shankar: I set the "not loaded" message on document load, then replace it with "loaded" if/when the iFrame contents are loaded. This is _exactly_ the same as what you are doing, just terser (and except that you forgot to call `checkIsDone` again onLoad; yours does nothing at all after the iframe loads).

Comment: Yes, I missed to set the default status message. But I still dont understand if OP wants to do anything after the iframe loads. You mean we should have that code on iframe load? Then we does he have if else condition to set different message?

Answer (score 0):

Well, `NOTDONE` will *never* appear because there is no `isDone` variable that can evaluate `true`. Also it seems that that logic is reversed.

Instead, set the "not done" message when your main document loads, then replace it with the "done" message when the iFrame document loads:

```
// on document load:
$(function() {
   // set "waiting" message:
   $("#loadingStatus").html("Waiting for your advertisements to load...");

   // on iframe load:
   $('#myIFrame').load(function() {
       // set "done waiting" message:
       $("#loadingStatus").html($("#isDone").html());
   });
});
```

That's it; that's all the Javascript you need. Take that horrid `onLoad` attribute out of your `iframe` markup and give the thing an ID:

```
<iframe id="myIFrame" src="<?php echo $r['url']; ?>" width="100%" height="90%" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0">
<p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

> function **isDone**()
>   {
>       if(**isDone**){

I think your problem may be that you have a boolean variable called `isDone` and your function definition variable is called `isDone`, one of these should be called something else.

Comment: And where is this boolean variable? I see no trace of it.

Comment: When debugging `isDone` is resulting to the HTML Div Objects, but this is just one of the problems, as Armando mentioned, you have to define it

Comment: @Tomalak, I was referring to a boolean variable since he used it in that way in the conditional `if(isDone)`, but you're right, it should be defined somewhere.

Comment: @vol7on: Indeed. You were referring to a boolean variable that did not exist.

Comment: Yeah, there seems to be a lot wrong with the supplied example.  I hope he knows that's there no true way of knowing if a iFrame has been fully loaded.

Comment: @vol7on: One can, indeed, only hope.